# Loading Images From a Link without Refreshing Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I created some widgets in my Wordpress theme, I want create representation for some of my widget fields, For example I create Twitter widget, it is contain the VIDEO_ID field, I created link named (info),

I want when anyone don't Know how get twitter VIDEO_ID, Then click on (info) link, to show it the explanation image on screen without refresh page.

How I can Show images by clicking on info link to show images without refresh the page and then click on close button to close the image?

Comment: What have you tried? Where is the current source code [Attempt(s)] or do you expect us to create it for you with no effort of your own?

Comment: I know my order it is do by ajax and jquery but i'm beginner in these libraries in my word press folder i create doc folder it is contain all representation  images when i click on info link directly the page refresh and show the image in another page. i want don't refresh page when i click on the info link.

Comment: When you submit a question, it's a good idea to post the relevant source code and display your attempts. This will allow others to explain why it isn't working as intended and give you solution(s) to your problem(s). Also **"my order it is"** Sounds like homework so I would recommend doing some research.

Comment: Only i have HTML link tag like this `<a href="myimage.jpg">Info</a>`

Comment: Well anchor tags are used for navigation and setting the href to the path of the image will navigate the user to the image. If you do some research you will learn how to stop a anchor tag from navigating and a little more research will help you understand how to use eventhandlers like `click` or attributes like `onclick` then you will need to create a function to access the attribute that contains the image name/path so you can make use of it. Until you make a good attempt at doing this and display the source code (Relevant source code), I will not help you other that this post.

Answer (score 0):

use a Modal to present your image.
You can refer to bootstrap modal http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp